# Recursive Queries CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I'm sitting with an example from "Murach's SQL Server 2016 for developers" book. The example illustrates how to code recursive CTS in SQL. Im much aware of recursion functions(in C#)  but i can't somehow understand how the sql recursion logic works.
Here is the example:

```
USE Examples;

WITH EmployeesCTE AS
(
        -- Anchor member
        SELECT EmployeeID, 
            FirstName + ' ' + LastName As EmployeeName, 
            1 As Rank
        FROM Employees
        WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
        -- Recursive member
        SELECT Employees.EmployeeID, 
            FirstName + ' ' + LastName, 
            Rank + 1
        FROM Employees
            JOIN EmployeesCTE
            ON Employees.ManagerID = EmployeesCTE.EmployeeID
)
SELECT *
FROM EmployeesCTE
ORDER BY Rank, EmployeeID;
```

This query returns a hierarchical level of employees in the organization.

My question: In a recursion function you would see a decrementing variable that terminates the recursion (by reaching a base case). My question is: Where is the corresponding part in EmployeesCTE? Please help me understand the logic.

Comment: Here `INNER JOIN` works as a filter and its `ON` condition server as a "terminator" as long as the underlying table does not have any circular references.

Comment: Out of experience, I'd like to draw your attention to the fact that this will perform bad on large data. Alternatively, consider adding RootManagerID to the Employees table. Then `SELECT EmployeeID, ManagerID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName As EmployeeName FROM Employees WHERE RootManagerID = @RootManagerID`. Then Build your tree on the application level instead. Beside the big performance benefits with this approach, it also allows you to further boost the performance by creating an index on `RootManagerID`.

Comment: @yazanpro, this will *perform bad on large data* as it is a *hidden RBAR*...

Comment: @Shnugo That's right.

Comment: Hi arif, is this question answered? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what we call "recursive CTE" should really be called an iterative CTE. The idea is that in order to define a recursive table (`EmployeesCTE` in this case), we start by creating some initial rows, in this case this is done by

```
   SELECT EmployeeID, 
        FirstName + ' ' + LastName As EmployeeName, 
        1 As Rank
    FROM Employees
    WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
```

(notice that this contains no reference to `EmployeesCTE` so it's not recursive), and then we iterate an expression, in this case

```
    SELECT Employees.EmployeeID, 
        FirstName + ' ' + LastName, 
        Rank + 1
    FROM Employees
        JOIN EmployeesCTE
        ON Employees.ManagerID = EmployeesCTE.EmployeeID
```

to generate some more rows. We do that until that expression returns no rows. In this expression `EmployeesCTE` refers to the previous version of that table, and by evaluating it, we calculate the next version of that table.

So the condition that stops the recursion (or rather iteration) is that the recursive expression yielded no new rows.

Now lets look closer at how all the above apply to the particular example that you gave. Our initial set of rows consists of employees that have no manager (we call them rank 1 employees). Then we find all the employees that are managed by the employees found in the previous step (we call them rank 2 employees). Then we find the employees are managed by rank 2 employees and call the rank 3, and so on. Eventually we will reach a step where no new employees can be found (assuming of course that the managed by relation has no cycles).

Answer (score 1):

As you are familiar with C# you might think of this like a complex *object modell*.

Just imagine a simple Windows.Forms.Form with its controls. Each control has a Controls-collection itself. In a database you could think of a self referencing table, where each row points to its parent row (top object points to NULL), like your employees point to their next boss up the hierarchy.

There is a top object with a method `Refresh()`. When you call this, the function does something on its own content and calls `Refresh()` on its inner collection. The collection calls `Refresh()` on all its members. All of them do something and call `Refresh()` on their inner collections. This runs down the nested model until you reach Controls with empty Controly-collection.

This is more something like a *top-down-cascade*. It can be quite tricky actually to stop a recursive CTE intentionally with a condition as you would not get the last row which carries the breaking condition.

The second part of the recursive CTE comes to a natural end, when the `JOIN` operation does not return any rows...

In your case you could read this as

- anchor: fetch all employees which do not have a boss (highest level)
- Now ask the list for all employees which have one of them as their manager (second level)
- Go down *row-by-row* and fetch all employees which have the second-level-person as their manager
- Continue until there are no more depending employees

And be aware of the fact, that a recursive CTE is - by design - a slow approach, as it is a *hidden RBAR*.

Answer (score 0):

May be some needs to do TOP-DOWN MS SQL to propagate THE TOP level value down through all Leveles (in some cases, only then top is better ;-)

```
    SELECT  ID      AS ID
        ,   parent  AS parent
        ,   limit   AS limit
        ,   NULL    AS maxParentLimit -- place holder
        INTO #StructLimit_CTE
        FROM StructLimit_CTE
    CREATE INDEX #StructLimit_CTE_id ON #StructLimit_CTE(ID)
    --SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #StructLimit_CTE -- 1000000+ in my case, so MS needs index  :-)

    ;WITH maxParentLimit (ID, ParentLimit, limit) as 
    ( select ID 
            , limit 
            , limit             
            from #StructLimit_CTE
            where parent IS NULL -- = 0
        union all
            select o.ID                                     
                , IIF( o.limit > ParentLimit, o.limit, ParentLimit) -- take the biggst, when we have one, think about NULL-s
                , o.limit   
            from #StructLimit_CTE o
            join maxParentLimit n on n.ID = o.parent -- recursion
    )
    UPDATE #StructLimit_CTE SET maxParentLimit = m.ParentLimit 
        FROM #StructLimit_CTE   AS o    
        JOIN maxParentLimit AS m    ON o.ID = m.ID
    -- or use (LEFT) JOIN when proper
```